# Selenium Action class perform method throws " org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException:" when run on eclipse

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Running the Selenium Action class perform method throws " org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException:" on eclipse. Can anyone advise on how to resolve it.

This is the code

```
package secondpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class MyTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get(baseUrl);           
        WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home"));
        WebElement td_Home = driver
                .findElement(By
                .xpath("//html/body/div"
                + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
                + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
                + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
                + "/table/tbody/tr"));    

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action mouseOverHome = builder
                .moveToElement(link_Home)
                .build();

        String bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
        System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);        
        **mouseOverHome.perform();**        
        bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
        System.out.println("After hover: " + bgColor);
        driver.quit();
}
}
```

This is console log:

```
1487695499339   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:2786
Feb 21, 2017 5:44:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1487695500651   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\ikenna\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.DJOOcSkDuPdH
1487695500754   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
1487695500923   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:62601
1487695520078   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62601
JavaScript error: about:blank line 4 > eval, line 1: ReferenceError: gBrowser is not defined
Feb 21, 2017 5:45:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Before hover: rgb(255, 165, 0)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/be1883b8-da2a-401a-bcaa-5b73650a52b7/moveto did not match a known command
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'ikenna-PC', ip: '192.168.1.120', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20170125094131, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=7940, browserVersion=51.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: be1883b8-da2a-401a-bcaa-5b73650a52b7
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:50)
    at secondpackage.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:34)
```

I am using selenium 3.0.1 driver on firefox 51.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has not been implemented in the Gecko/Marinette driver yet.

Track the status of the implementation:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/159

As a work around, you can do most things with the JavascriptExecutor: 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: Also, in my own testing I get a NotImplementedExcecption with Safari and WebDriverWait. I haven't found a ticket for that, though.